# RTSP live stream on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, live-streaming

I try to make a live stream on Android. I tried lots of ways, but none of them
worked. How can I do it?

This is example of RTSP:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(KralStream.getTvStreamUrl().toString());
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

> Exeption :05-26 10:22:46.186: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerService(10157): 
>   create PVPlayer 05-26 10:23:06.382: 
>   ERROR/PlayerDriver(10157): Command 
>   PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or 
>   info -1 05-26 10:23:06.382: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(23800): error (1, 
>   -1) 05-26 10:23:06.382: ERROR/MediaPlayer(23800): Error (1,-1)

RTSP:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtsp://strm-3.tr.medianova.tv/rkraltv/rkraltv");
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

It gives this message:

> "Sorry, this video 
>   cannot ve played." Exeptions;05-26 
>   10:40:08.979: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerService(10157): 
>   create PVPlayer 05-26 10:40:09.188: 
>   INFO/ActivityManager(10163): Displayed 
>   activity 
>   com.giantrabbit.nagare/.KralTvNow: 433 
>   ms (total 433 ms) 05-26 10:40:11.702: 
>   WARN/PowerManagerService(10163): Timer 
>   0x3->0x3|0x1 05-26 10:40:29.061: 
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(24284): info/warning 
>   (1, 26) 05-26 10:40:29.061: 
>   INFO/MediaPlayer(24284): Info (1,26) 
>   05-26 10:40:29.100: 
>   ERROR/PlayerDriver(10157): Command 
>   PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or 
>   info -1 05-26 10:40:29.104: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(24284): error (1, 
>   -1) 05-26 10:40:29.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(24284): Error (1,-1)

RTSP:

```
mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
holder = mPreview.getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
extras = getIntent().getExtras();

public void play() {
    try {
        Uri video = KralStream.getTvStreamUrl();
        Toast.makeText(this, video.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Exeption:

> 05-26 10:36:57.589: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerService(10157): 
>   create PVPlayer 05-26 10:37:20.542: 
>   ERROR/PlayerDriver(10157): Command 
>   PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or 
>   info -1 05-26 10:37:20.542: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(24240): error (1, 
>   -1) 05-26 10:37:20.565: WARN/PlayerDriver(10157): 
>   PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete 05-26 
>   10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): error: 
>   Prepare failed.: status=0x1 05-26 
>   10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): 
>   java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: 
>   status=0x1 05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native 
>   Method) 05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   com.giantrabbit.nagare.KralTvNow.play(KralTvNow.java:162) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   com.giantrabbit.nagare.KralTvNow.surfaceCreated(KralTvNow.java:215) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:536) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6796) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6796) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1894) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
>   Method) 05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.682: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(24240): at 
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
>   Method) 05-26 10:37:20.737: 
>   INFO/MediaPlayer(24240): Info (1,26) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.737: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(24240): Error (1,-1) 
>   05-26 10:37:20.868: 
>   INFO/ActivityManager(10163): Displayed 
>   activity 
>   com.giantrabbit.nagare/.KralTvNow: 
>   25864 ms (total 25864 ms) 05-26 
>   10:37:23.777: 
>   WARN/PowerManagerService(10163): Timer 
>   0x3->0x3|0x1

This is an example of HTTP:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://ikral.garantisistem.com:1935/ikral/smil:kral.smil/playlist.m3u8");
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Exception:

> 05-26 10:16:24.276: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayerService(10157): 
>   create PVPlayer 05-26 10:16:24.292: 
>   ERROR/(10157): IIIIIII Inside 
>   Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferWriteDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: 
>   INFO/PlayerDriver(10157): buffering 
>   (100) 05-26 10:16:24.346: 
>   ERROR/(10157): IIIIIII Inside 
>   Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.346: ERROR/(10157): 
>   IIIIIII Inside Constructor of 
>   PVMFMemoryBufferReadDataStreamImpl 
>   05-26 10:16:24.350: 
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(23736): info/warning 
>   (1, 26) 05-26 10:16:24.354: 
>   ERROR/PlayerDriver(10157): Command 
>   PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or 
>   info -10 05-26 10:16:24.354: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(23736): error (-10, 
>   -10) 05-26 10:16:24.354: WARN/PlayerDriver(10157): 
>   PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete 05-26 
>   10:16:24.393: INFO/MediaPlayer(23736): 
>   Info (1,26) 05-26 10:16:24.393: 
>   ERROR/MediaPlayer(23736): Error 
>   (-10,-10)

HTTP:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://ikral.garantisistem.com:1935/ikral/smil:kral.smil/playlist.m3u8");
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

It gives the message:

> "Sorry, this video cannot ve played."

[image]

Comment: Which phone you are using for testing?.. Some phones like MOTOROLA won't support some video formats. But the phones like Nexus will support this video streaming formats

Comment: I tested on Samsung Galaxy S and Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Comment: url is :rtsp://strm-3.tr.medianova.tv/rkraltv/rkraltv 
codec type h264

Comment: Hi could you please tell me how u managed to play rtsp on android??

Comment: Sometimes it happens only on Simulator. Is your video format H.264? If so, there can not be problem about streaming the video. However, you can see the error message in any case. If you give the Internet permission, try doing it on a real device.

Comment: hi ........ did u got the solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Please add network permission in your  AndroidManifest.xml file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Android can handle RTSP streams without any flash. You try to type the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) in the browser address bar directly and the external player will automatically open to play the URL.

If it gives an error then you will need to check the video format supported by Android. You can check the RTSP stream URL example from [Wowza Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wowza_Streaming_Engine). Reference the URL for the RTSP stream troubleshooting from Wowza Media Server: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?62-RTSP-streaming-troubleshooting-guide-%28RTSP-RTP-playback%29. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the format of the video. Try to make it [3GP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP_and_3G2).